# Animate fragment slideup and slide down

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-transitions

I want to slide up a fragment on its entry and slide down it on its exit. It should be pretty simple but I am facing issues.

Animation code :
Slide Down - >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
```

Slide Up ->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
    android:fromYDelta="0%p"
    android:toYDelta="100%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" />
```

This is my code for fragment transition :

```
try {
            if (fragment != null && mSelectedTabIndex != NO_TAB) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = createTransactionWithOptions(transactionOptions);
                detachCurrentFragment(ft);
                    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_up,R.animator.slide_down,R.animator.slide_up,R.animator.slide_down);

                ft.add(mContainerId, fragment, generateTag(fragment));
                ft.commit();

                executePendingTransactions();
                mFragmentStacks.get(mSelectedTabIndex).push(fragment);

                mCurrentFrag = fragment;
                if (mTransactionListener != null) {
                    mTransactionListener.onFragmentTransaction(mCurrentFrag, TransactionType.PUSH);
                }

            }
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But I am not getting desired results. And I don't wish to replace the fragment but always add the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

> Try using this simple solution from the anim folder animations.

Replace
this

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, firstFragment, "fragment_class_name");
```

with

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment, "fragment_class_name");
```

**Example**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_up);
fragmentManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, firstFragment, "fragment_class_name");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragment_class_name");
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Reason to use add fragment
The important difference is:

`replace` removes the existing `fragment` and adds a new `fragment`..

but `add` retains the existing fragments and adds a new fragment that means existing fragment will be active and they wont be in 'paused' state hence when a back button is pressed `onCreateView()` is not called for the existing `fragment`(the `fragment` which was there before new `fragment` was added).

*See the screenshot*

[image]

Comment: update the code , please check... i changed to add from replace